# json.net - what data structure would produce JSON in this format?

Tags: .net, json, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to generate a JSON string in this format:

```
{
  "item": [
    {
      "text": "Past 7 days",
      "value": "274057"
    },
    [
      "38594",
      "39957",
      "35316",
      "35913",
      "36668",
      "45660",
      "41949"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I tried using the following structs with a JsonConvert.SerializeObject()

```
public struct itemheader {
        public string text;
        public decimal value;
}
public struct itemdata
{
    public itemheader header;
    public decimal[] data;
}
public struct TrendLineData
{
    public itemdata[] item;
}
```

So creating a variable of type TrendLineData and feeding it into JsonConvert.SerializeObject() gives me almost what I want, but I don't the "header" or "data" names.

I'm starting to think that this cannot be done with a SerializeObject()?

Comment: Your JSON looks strange. You have an array with in position 0 an object, and in position 1 another array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange output format, but if you don't mind changing your structs a bit you can get the result you want.  First, you will need to change the `item` member of your `TrendLineData` struct to be `object[]`, then you can put whatever you want in the array.  Also, if you want quotes around the numbers then they will need to be strings, not decimal.  Here is an example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TrendLineData data = new TrendLineData
        {
            item = new object[]
            { 
                new itemheader
                {
                    text = "Past 7 days",
                    value = "274057"
                },
                new string[]
                {
                    "38594",
                    "39957",
                    "35316",
                    "35913",
                    "36668",
                    "45660",
                    "41949"
                }
            }
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}

public struct TrendLineData
{
    public object[] item;
}

public struct itemheader
{
    public string text;
    public string value;
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "item": [
    {
      "text": "Past 7 days",
      "value": "274057"
    },
    [
      "38594",
      "39957",
      "35316",
      "35913",
      "36668",
      "45660",
      "41949"
    ]
  ]
}
```

If you want to keep your structs as they are, there are other options as well:

- You could use JObjects/JArrays to build your JSON structure manually and serialize that;
- You could use LINQ transformations on your structs to create an anonymous object in the "shape" you want and serialize that, or
- You could make a JsonConverter that will translate your object structure into the correct JSON.

If you want a demo of any of these techniques, let me know.

Comment: Thank you!  I really appreciate that.  The spec for the JSON, in case you are interested, comes from:  https://developer.geckoboard.com/#trendline-example

Answer (score 0):

That specific JSON cannot be directly accomplished with `SerializeObject` since you have both an array and an object type in the same array in the JSON. Within an array, you cannot mix different types of objects (either object structures or in your case object and arrays).

Comment: You can mix types if the array is `object[]`.